# R aggregation for percentage count

Tags: r, ggplot2

With a data frame `df1` like below - I need to create a visualization for  percentage number of cars by `make`

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|reg   |make  |model  |year|abs  |gears|fm|
+-----------------------------------------+
|ax1234|Toyota|Corolla|1999|true |6    |0 |
|ax1235|Toyota|Corolla|1999|false|5    |0 |
|ax1236|Toyota|Corolla|1992|false|4    |NA|
|ax1237|Toyota|Camry  |2001|true |7    |1 |
|ax1238|Honda |Civic  |1994|true |5    |NA|
|ax1239|Honda |Civic  |2000|false|6    |0 |
|ax1240|Honda |Accord |1992|false|4    |NA|
|ax1241|Nissan|Sunny  |2001|true |6    |0 |
|ax1242|      |       |1998|false|6    |0 |
|ax1243|NA    |NA     |1992|false|4    |NA|
+-----------------------------------------+
```

I need to find the percentage of cars by `make` - I do as follows.

```
df2 <- aggregate(reg ~ addNA(make), df1, function(x){ return (length(x)/nrow(df1))})
> df2
  addNA(make) reg
1             0.1
2       Honda 0.3
3      Nissan 0.1
4      Toyota 0.4
5        <NA> 0.1
>
```

Eventually, I plot a bar chart as follows.

```
df3 <- df2[order(-df2[,2]),]
ggplot(df3, aes(x=df3[,1], y=df3[,2])) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  xlab("make") + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent, name="perc")
```

which gives me the below plot.

Questions -

1. Is this a right way to get from data to the plot - better suggestions welcome
2. Why aren't the labels sorted in desc order of percentage in the plot?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend going through the many `ggplot2` tutorials online.  There are many ways that you could streamline your code, or make use of different tools but that will come with time and continued use.

I believe the biggest improvement you can make are in the use of bare variable names from the data you pass in your call.  You can also save yourself some typing with some broader knowledge of the different `geoms`

The second problem you face is that `ggplot` determines the order of the variables from the data in most cases.  With the discrete data you're passing, you need to create a `factor` in the proper order.  You were almost there, having sorted the data properly.  You just needed to get the create a factor out of it.

Your call:

```
df2 <- aggregate(reg ~ addNA(make), df, function(x){ return (length(x)/nrow(df))})

df3 <- df2[order(-df2[,2]),]

ggplot(df3, aes(x=df3[,1], y=df3[,2])) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  xlab("make") + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent, name="perc")
```

My call:

```
df2  <- aggregate(reg ~ make, df, function(x){ return (length(x)/nrow(df))})

order <- df2$make[order(-df2$reg)]

df2$make <- factor(df2$make, order)

ggplot(df2, aes(x = make, y = reg)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  labs(x = "Make", y = "Percent")
```

I make use of `geom_col` which is a shortcut of `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` and the `labs()` to set multiple labels in one call.

[image]

Comment: this works. However when I take a subset of df2, like df2[1:10,] the ordering is lost i.e with something like - `ggplot(df2[1:10,], aes(x = make, y = reg))` - how do we get the sort order by `reg` in the subset as well

Comment: Check your data and code carefully. If I run a subset like `df2[c(2,5),]` and plot it, it keeps the order.

Comment: when I use `ggplot(df2, aes(x = make, y = reg)) + ...` , ggplot displays the bars in the order - `Toyota, Honda, "", Nissan` , which is fine. However, when I subset the data to say I want only the top 3 makes by count percentage by calling `ggplot(df2[1:3,], aes(x = make, y = reg)) + ...` , ggplot displays  `Honda, "", Nissan`  - where as I was expecting it to display `Toyota, Honda, ""`

Answer (score 1):

For the order of the bars, as said, the trick is to use factors because ggplot2 will sort the characters in alphabetical order.

You can take advantage of the `dplyr` package to manipulate data and not having to store it at each step using the pipe `%>%`operator that passes the data as the first argument of the next function.
Here is my version:

```
library(dplyr)    # For data manipulation and the pipe (%>%) operator
library(forcats)  # For factor handling (here fct_reorder())
library(ggplot2)  # For plots
library(scales)   # For percent scale

# Start with the data frame and pass it with the pipe to the next function
df1 %>% 
  # Then we group it by make
  group_by(make) %>% 
  # We summarise by vreating a prop variable, n() returns the number of row by group
  summarise(prop = n()/nrow(df1)) %>% 
  # We then transform the make variable into a factor, the order of the level
  # given by -prop (to have it in decreasing order)
  mutate(make = fct_reorder(make, -prop)) %>% 
  # And we pass it to the plot
  # Notice the transition to + instead of %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = make, y = prop)) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_y_continuous(label = percent) +
    labs(x = "Make", y = "Percent")
```

Also note that for me, NAs are stored as `NA` and not as a character string `"NA"`, and as so will be plot as the last bar, regardless of the value.